# Fit larger DIV in IPAD

Tags: css, ipad

I have div which has height and width of 15360px respectively which is the designated area to drag my elements around. It is working fine on the desktops and laptops where the scroll bars will appear.

I have been using the media queries to work it on IPAD too, but when the site is viwed in IPAD the page gets shrinks because of the particular div which has the width and height of 15360px.

Can anyone suggest what can be done to make the Mammoth div to fit in IPAD so that page looks fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should play around with the `viewport` meta tag. See the documentation on MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag.

I think you're looking for no scaling and fixed width instead of device-width.